# Ember.js: Does App.X = Y essentially means "export default" in new ES6 module system?

Tags: ember.js

Sorry for the newbie question. I haven't started using Ember yet. At the moment I'm still studying whether it's suitable for our project. A big attraction of Ember for us is Ember Data. I've been reading the documentation on it. In a lot of the examples, I'd see the following pattern:

```
App.Requirement = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  temperature: attr('temperature')
});
```

In other places though, I'd see the following:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr(),
  lastName: DS.attr(),
  birthday: DS.attr()
});
```

Is the `App.X = Y` syntax just an obsolete way of exporting a class/function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ember-cli (using requirejs) versus Ember searching for classes on a global namespace.  Ember-cli is the current direction of the ember core team, and a pretty friendly tool to work with for generating ember applications.  Though for simple things such as in a jsbin, using the global namespace is super easy.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com